# Creating REST API in Swift using vapor unable to make a POST request

Tags: swift, rest, vapor

While learning how to use Swift and Vapor to create a REST api, while testing this API using postman, I am unable to make an API Post request, the error I receive is:

```swift
{
    "error": true,
    "reason": "Value of type 'String' required for key 'email'."  
}
```

I am using a PostgreSQL database reference the model. I feel something is wrong with my model.

Here is the model I am using:

```swift
final class Todo: PostgreSQLModel {
    var id: Int?
    var email: String
    var password: String
    var name_first: String
    var name_last: String
    var username: String

    init(id: Int?, email: String, name_first: String, name_last: String, username:String, password: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.email = email
        self.name_first = name_first
        self.name_last = name_last
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    }
}
```

Comment: See Vapor [Content](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/vapor/content/) docs. Have to `Todo` object be compliant with either the `Codable` or `Content` protocols. `Content` itself complies to `Codable`.

Comment: I'd say you are not sending the right POST's body. You didn't tell us what your request looks like. Can you include it (curl style is fine) in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was using postman wrong. I was passing things through the header the body my mistake.